# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"’

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have sqlite data base "DGN-WB_0.5.db" and I am trying to open it in R in order to see which tables are inside.

I tried:

```
library(RSQLite)
con = dbConnect(drv="SQLite",dbname="DGN-WB_0.5.db")
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

Can you please tell me why is this happening, do I need to import some other library?

I want to run something like this:

```
 alltables = dbListTables(con)
```

Comment: Did you already have `library(DBI)` included?

Comment: Hi, not but I just tried it and got output in the commend bellow

Answer (score 1):

Idk, but try this one

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "DGN-WB_0.5.db")
```

Comment: I tried it, I got this: > library(DBI)
> con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "DGN-WB_0.5.db")
Warning message:
Couldn't set synchronous mode: disk I/O error
Use `synchronous` = NULL to turn off this warning.